# Was "hi" used for something more than to say "hi de puta" and similar, insulting expressions?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia

In ancient times, "hi" was used in Spanish as a short form of "hijo", but only in insults:

> **[hi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KIAi6ga)**
>
> > Apóc.
>
> 1. m. y f. desus. **hijo**. Era u. en expresiones injuriosas, o a veces ponderativas. *Hi de puta. Hi de perro.*

Was this short form of "hijo" used for something more than in insulting or weighing expressions?

Comment: Si el DLE indica que se usaba en expresiones *ponderativas*, contraponiéndolo a expresiones *injuriosas*, creo que la pregunta con el nuevo formato se responde por si sola

Comment: @user17232 A veces la pregunta se matiza un poco en el texto de la misma, con el fin de no hacer el título demasiado largo.

Answer (score 5):

According to the "Diccionario de autoridades" it seems like its use always had a
negative connotation:

> [Diccionario de Autoridades - Tomo IV (1734)](http://web.frl.es/DA.html)
>
> HI. s. m. Lo mismo que Hijo: y siempre parece se usaba para denostar o reprehender a alguno: y assí se decía regularmente Hi de puta, Hi da ruin; pero yá no tiene uso. Latín. *Filius*. MARIAN. Hist. Esp. lib. 17. cap. 13. Frosarte, historiador Francés deste tiempo, dice que D. Henrique, al entrar de aquel aposento dixo: Donde está el hi de puta Judío que se llama Rey de Castilla? y que Don Pedro respondió: Tu eres el hi de puta, que yo hijo soi del Rey Don Alonso.

Comment: La diplomacia no era tan estimada como hoy en día jeje

Answer (score 3):

En el *Diccionario de autoridades* despues de la entrada **HI** que ha mostrado @MauricioMartinez tenemos esto:

> **HI DE PUTA.** Algunas veces se dice esta expressión sin que denote
>   injuria o denuesto; sino se usa de ella como admirándose, y entonces
>   es interjección que alaba alguna cosa. CERV. Quix. tom. 1. cap. 13. O
>   hi de puta bellaco, y como es cathólico! Veis ahí, dixo el del bosque
>   en oyendo el hi *de puta* de Sancho, como habeis alabado este vino
>   llamándole hi *de puta*.

Gonzalo Corrreas en su *Vocabulario de refranes y frases proverbiales* dice:

> Hi de puta. (Encareciendo y alabando en bien ó en mal; hi de puta, 
>   puto.)

El libro *Actas de las VIII Jornadas sobre la Historia de Tauste* también habla sobre el tema y su ambigüedad:

> Los giros con *hi de...* no son, de otra parte, siempre vocativos, sino
>   que, a menudo, representan exclamaciones o interjecciones: en obras
>   teatrales del Siglo de Oro, por ejemplo, las mujeres usan *hi de ruin* o
>   *hi de puta* hablando entre ellas (de modo análogo a como emplean esos
>   giros los varones entre ellos; o ellas con ellos, y viceversa). A
>   menudo la expresión se refuerza con otra interjección *–¡oh!– (¡Oh hi
>   de ruin!)* y no siempre es sintomática de rechazo, enfado o enojo, sino
>   que también puede adoptar un sentido admirativo o ponderativo.

Por lo que se ve en todos estos textos hi nunca aparece solo sino en la fórmula *hi de [algo]* pero no siempre tiene un sentido peyorativo o de ofensa.